# MySQL: Output ID based on SUM data in one column based attributes in another column

Tags: mysql, sum

SQL Table:

| Customer | Type | Payment |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Apples | 5 |
| 1 | Apples | 5 |
| 1 | Oranges | 1 |
| 1 | Oranges | 2 |
| 2 | Apples | 7 |
| 2 | Oranges | 3 |
| 2 | Oranges | 6 |

Based on the above, looking to determine which customers have paid more for apples compared to oranges as a sum of all their payments.

In the case of the above table,

Customer 1 - Apples 10 > Oranges 3

Customer 2 - Apples 7 < Oranges 9

Thus the SQL should output Customer 1

I have attempted multiple queries, with the following as the most promising but getting an invalid use of group function error code 1111.

```
SELECT a.customer 
FROM (SELECT customer, SUM(payment) AS orangespaid FROM table
    WHERE type ='Oranges'
    GROUP BY customer) o
JOIN table AS a ON a.customer = o.customer
WHERE type = 'Apples' and SUM(payment) > orangespaid
GROUP BY customer
ORDER BY customer;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of ways to achieve that.

Here's how you do without sub-query:

```
SELECT Customer,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Type='Apples' THEN Payment ELSE 0 END) AS Apples,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Type='Oranges' THEN Payment ELSE 0 END) AS Oranges
  FROM table1
  GROUP BY Customer
HAVING Apples > Oranges;
```

Or like this:

```
SELECT Customer,
      SUM(IF(Type='Apples',Payment,0)) > SUM(IF(Type='Oranges',Payment,0)) Chk
  FROM table1
  GROUP BY Customer
HAVING Chk=1
```

Or a slight modification of the query above, instead of checking the value in `SELECT` then filter from `HAVING`, why not just directly do the checking in `HAVING`:

```
SELECT Customer
  FROM table1
  GROUP BY Customer
HAVING SUM(IF(Type='Apples',Payment,0)) > SUM(IF(Type='Oranges',Payment,0)) != 0;
```

The first query can also be done in similar way.

[Demo fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=74d819addfec8b298405d83c75d4d3d3)

Side note:

As for the difference between using `CASE` or `IF`, it's basically operates the same so it's more to individual preference. I mostly opt to use `CASE` because of readability and easier to edit (not much usage of parentheses/brackets) but using `IF` almost every time is shorter to write.

Answer (score 1):

Try moving the SUM into a second subquery instead

```
SELECT a.customer 
FROM (SELECT customer, SUM(payment) AS orangespaid FROM table
    WHERE type ='Oranges'
    GROUP BY customer) o
JOIN (SELECT customer, SUM(payment) AS applespaid FROM table
    WHERE type ='Apples'
    GROUP BY customer) AS a ON a.customer = o.customer
WHERE applespaid > orangespaid
ORDER BY customer;
```

Comment: Using MySQL Workbench here, getting the following error:
Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'orangespaid' in 'having clause'
Also tried o.orangespaid but no luck

Answer (score 1):

You should try with `sum(case when)` for each type you want, it might not the best solution but it works.

```
select a.customer
from (select as1.Customer, 
sum(case when type = 'Oranges' then payment else 0 end) AS orangespaid, 
sum(case when type = 'Apples' then payment else 0 end) AS applespaid
from as1 group by as1.Customer) a
where applespaid > orangespaid
```

[dbfiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=7cc7918c248e09d32ff057dae574363b)